# ggplot2 doesn't load in R/RStudio - Application not responding

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

I have installed ggplot2 version 1.0.1 on R version 3.1.3, using

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies=T)
```

Checking for the installation:

```
find.package('ggplot2')
```

returns

```
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/ggplot2"
```

However, when I try to load it

```
library('ggplot2')
```

I get the spinning wheel of death.

I successfully installed and used it on Windows 7 ages ago, version 1.0.1 on R 3.1.2. However, on my Mac (OS X Yosemite), I can't seem to avoid it freezing on me when I try to load it.

I'm using RStudio 0.98.1103 on the Mac and 0.98.501 on the PC, but going to the R GUI on the Mac doesn't solve the issue, so I don't think it's RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on why this occurs, but I just tried installing from source, as recommended in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337477/unable-to-install-ggplot2-package-in-r-on-windows-8-1) about a different error message on Windows.

```
install.packages("ggplot2", type="source",dependencies = TRUE)
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with R version 3.2.2. The install.packages command as suggested in the other response unfortunately did not work for me.
 
I got ggplot2 loaded by downloading and installing all the packages below. Download each package manually from CRAN (OS X Mavericks binaries), then go to the terminal, cd to the Download folder, and type:  R CMD INSTALL *.tgz

- colorspace_1.2-6.tgz

  digest_0.6.8.tgz

  ggplot2_1.0.1.tgz

  gtable_0.1.2.tgz

  magrittr_1.5.tgz

  MASS_7.3-44.tgz

  munsell_0.4.2.tgz

  plyr_1.8.3.tgz

  proto_0.3-10.tgz

  Rcpp_0.12.1.tgz

  reshape2_1.4.1.tgz

  scales_0.3.0.tgz

  stringi_1.0-1.tgz

  stringr_1.0.0.tgz